# git-pull omits a file

Tags: git, git-pull, git-commit, git-status

Git is saying everything is up to date but there is a file missing on one node's copy of the source tree. On system A:

```
$ ls -l
abc.py
xyz.py

$ git add xyz.py
$ git status
nothing added to commit...

$ git commit
nothing added to commit...

$ git push
Everything up-to-date
```

On system B:

```
$ git pull
Already up-to-date
$ ls -l
abc.py
```

My question is: What happened to file xyz.py on system B? Why did the pull not create it on System B?

Comment: Are you push/pulling from the same branch?

Comment: Yes, there's only one branch in this example.